# pitfalls of IIFEs with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, iife

I have an application made with angularJS, whole application is composed of IIFEs(Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Every module, directive, controller is itself an IIFE and they are around 100s.

I want to know what is the performance pitfall when an app has so many IIFEs.

It is OK to use IIFEs with AngularJS?

How good is using libs like browserify and requirejs with AngularJS for managing the dependencies?

Can you please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to ask first is whether you've got some internal parts within the IIFE that you don't want to expose to the global scope.

The whole point of creating a closure in this manner is to mimic encapsulation and avoid polluting the global scope.

The performance pitfall is not so easy to measure; I think the performance issue is negligible when you create the IIFE (don't forget you're just creating a function). One performance issue that I might think of is that when you reference a function variable form an inner function, you need to travel through the scope chain and get it from the closure object.

I would recommend you to look at patterns like module pattern, revealing module pattern etc. I personally use the revealing module pattern.

Browserify and requireJS are two libraries that implement two different specs; the commonJS and AMD respectively. These two specifications try to accommodate a functionality that is  not supported by ES3 or ES5; That is a way of defining module and then loading them in specified locations.

If you want to define modules and load them synchronously in a similar manner to hose nodeJS works, you can use Browserify. In addition, Browserify  allows you to use the same modules both for client-side and server-side (as long as you're using nodeJS).

On the other hand if you want to asynchronously load your modules you can go with AMD and  requireJS, but you won't be able to reuse them on the back-end.

Finally, bare in mind that everything you've mentioned is not directly connected to angularJS; those are some good JavaScript practises to overcome some issues of the language itself. It can be well used whether you're working with angular or not.

I would recommend that you use either browserify or requireJS; it will benefit you in the long run. Just imagine having 100 JS files; you would need to out the manually into your html in the correct order based on the dependency graph. You can easily come across issues like race conditions where one file should have been inserted before another one.

As for the performance overhead of IIFEs, you shouldn't have any serious issues.

Comment: many thanks for your comments, i found requirejs as overhead with angularjs as angularjs does DI own its own, requirejs is fine with libs like backbonejs that doesn't have concept of knowing what function to call when. For angularjs I find browserify as good.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer said, IIFEs are a good general practice, independent of AngularJS.

If you're concerned about the performance of IIFEs, go ahead and check out these performance tests on JSPerf (or write your own):

- http://jsperf.com/iife-antecedents-in-js
- http://jsperf.com/immediate-anonymous-function-invocation

While some ways of IIFE creation are clearly much slower than others, I wouldn't worry about the performance of IIFEs unless you're in a large loop.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i found only the global scope issue while using IIFEs, rest of the things are fine. Attaching many things on global scope or creating too many closures makes things difficult for GC. As per the chrome dev tools the farther the distance from GC root the better GC will be.

Comment: That's a reasonable assertion about relationship between distance from root and GC. Do you have a citation for it?